Manually installing plugins
For reasons I cannot explain, my employer has blocked access to github on the command line, so I cannot git clone any repos - but I do still have access to the github website and can download the zip file without problem.
My question is, how can I use the zip file of a Vim plugin to install it into Vim? Is it even possible? I've Googled for help and found a few sites which claim to tell you all about how to do manual installs, but they all start with 'First, git clone the repo...'

If you are able to download the files (e.g.: vim-surround from vim-surround) you can:

Create a folder ~/vimfiles/pack/dist/start/vim-surround
Move the downloaded files in that start folder
Restart Vim

More information with :help packages.
Remark: If you want to keep control on the activation of the plugin in your vimrc file you could instead:

Create a folder ~/vimfiles/pack/dist/opt/vim-surround
Move the downloaded files in that opt folder
Add pack vim-surround in your vimrc file.
Restart Vim


In other words: :help packages ;)

If you want to stick to your usual tools and workflow, chances are you can use your plugin manager with local copies of plugins.
Most plugin managers will support it.
However, you don't need one.
They're just a convenient tools to download plugins from GitHub (or somewhere else) and set them up, build helptags, etc.
You could use the popular vim-plug which consists of a single file you'd have to download (somewhere else and copy to your machine).
Take a look at this line from their usage example:
" Unmanaged plugin (manually installed and updated)
Plug '~/my-prototype-plugin'

You just need to replace ~/my-prototype-plugin with the location of your downloaded and unzipped plugin.
This approach could be beneficial when you want to re-use your vimrc from a PC with GitHub access.
You could prefix a local path to your plugins with
:%s@^Plug '@&my-plugin-download-dir/@

